# Libgdx viewports

Tags: android, libgdx

It seems like a viewport is useless, but I AM PROBABLY MISSING SOMETHING.

For example I wanted to make a game where I have an object and if I hit the left or the right end of the screen I DIE! So if I used Gdx.graphis.getWidth() and 0 everything would work fine.

OK, but let's setup the viewport = new ExtendViewport(500, 800, camera);
Cool I have not virtual pixels of 500 and 800 === > 5 : 8
Then I type the logic for hitting the end screen, so if object.x < 0 or object.x > 800 ----> object DIES!

But now I start the game on a tablet which has the resolution of 1500 x 2000 ===> 3 : 4, now everything is wrong, the whole screen is moved to the left, so 0 still works but 800 is not the end of the right screen edge.

Then I go use FitViewport and the collision of the left and right edge is now moved, because of a different aspect ratio.

Seems like I can use strechViewport, or just manually code the stuff... But I know I am missing something, because IT MUST HAVE ITS USE.

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: judging from what you want to do, do you think setting a maximum limit for your viewport would help you out? check out the api https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/ExtendViewport.html#ExtendViewport-float-float-float-float-, This might help you limit the size of the viewport

Comment: Well setting some max? I cannot even reach the max... Although now I do my games different... I program the PlayState, the way you play the game the old fashion way with Gdx.graphics.getWidth and getHeight(), everything else from menus to option and stuff I do with ViewPorts, it seems like the only solution

Answer (score 0):

First of all in my opinion it is good habit to center the camera at (0, 0) coordinates. Then you will have always `-screenWidth/2` as left screen's edge's position and `screenWidth/2` for the right side.

Secondly you should not use screen's coordinates directly when using viewport. [Viewport](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/Viewport.html) has a method to transform screen's to viewport's coordinates:

```
    unproject(Vector2 screenCoords)
```

it has also backward method

```
    project(Vector2 worldCoords)
```

These will make you able to keep always same type of coordinates no matter how big display will be.

Comment: Projecting is useful for touch events only or not? And when the aspect ratio changes, I then used ExtendViewport so I have the background through the whole phone, but the actual PLAYABLE screen part is moved away from the LEFT and the RIGHT EDGE OF SCREEN... so after the edges are like at -50 and 550 instead of 0 and 500, I can multiply everything by the aspect_ratio, but then it seems like it is even useless to use the ViewPorts. What am I missing here? Could you check my code and tell me what I am missing here: http://pastebin.com/UY0BzBNp , the SQUARE class has only a sprite and hitbox